# Why in Java printing a character prints character but adding two characters adds ascii?

Tags: java, ascii

Consider below code snippet

```
public class TestAsc
{
  public static void main(String args[]){
   System.out.println('a');
  }
}
```

Here O/P is a. Now the same code snippet with an addition as below.

```
public class TestAsc
{
  public static void main(String args[]){
   System.out.println('a' + 'a');
  }
}
```

Here o/p is 194. i.e addition of ASCII values. I knew by googling it out and from some posts in StackOverflow too that, addition of char would result in ASCII addition.
But my question is *why* and *how* does it happen internally? And why isn't ASCII printed when I placed only 'a' in `System.out.println`!

Comment: What do you mean internally?

Comment: This is the syntax for it. You can print a twice by using - System.out.println("" + a + a);

Comment: By internally, I meant how does the compiler/jvm acts to convert. It's a bit clear now on going through the link.